# LAST function in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

I have written a cypher query to get the last node of a path.
This is my query to get the path:

```
MATCH mypath = (p:Person {firstName: 'John'})-[:TAKEN|:NEXT_MEASURMENT*]->(endnode)
RETURN mypath
```

This code returns the correct path which is:
[image: The pink nodes have the same label but with different date properties]

What is not working properly is that when I write a cypher code to return the last node of the path, I mean:

```
MATCH mypath = (p:Person {firstName: 'John'})-[:TAKEN|:NEXT_MEASURMENT*]->(endnode)
RETURN LAST(nodes(mypath))
```

Instead of returning just the last node, it returns all the pink nodes:
[image]

I would appreciate it if you could help me in finding my mistake here.

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectation is that when you return `mypath` you are actually returning multiple paths.

And when you return `LAST(nodes(mypath))` you are returning the end node from multiple paths.

If you switch your return to *Table* in the left nav of the browser you should see multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It was true. It returns all the matched paths. Regards